# Why is my relative format looking awkward?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to build a relative layout for my school project. The center element refuses to be the same height and distance from the top as the others. How do I fix this?

Edit: To clarify the icons are textViews using fontAwesome. Debugging a little I switched the icons of the left and center containers and the center was still higher so I believe it is an issue of formatting.

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/icDate"
                android:textAppearance="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:text="@string/fa_calender"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center">
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:textAppearance="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:id="@+id/tvDate"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center">
            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/icDuration"
                android:textAppearance="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:text="@string/fa_time"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center">
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:textAppearance="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:id="@+id/tvDuration"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center">
            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/icDistance"
                android:textAppearance="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:text="@string/fa_road"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center">
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:textAppearance="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:id="@+id/tvDistance"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center">
            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

with bg to highlight issue:

[image]

without bg

[image]

Comment: Maybe the size of the image is different?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this.

1、Use [Paint](https://support.microsoft.com/zh-tw/instantanswers/8a779cf7-3362-4948-a65e-e3a78c86f9a8/download-paint) to make sure your size of image is totally same.

2、adjust your image size in specific

```
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
```

Comment: unfortunately they are simply icons from a font.

Comment: don't use fontAwesome make thing simple. Of course if its designated for use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` in all of your `LinearLayout`?

Remember that you must center the **icon** plus the **date** or whatever text is below the icon. Thus, you must center the container of both which is the `LinearLayout`.

Also, using the`android:textAlignment="center"` centers the text in its own borders. It doesn't center it in its parent layout.